# Can I use a higher order component to add an onClick to my component without adding a wrapper DOM element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, higher-order-components

We're moving an existing application for a specific touch screen to React. The screen has some sensitivity issues so we want to customise the `onClick` behaviour of all the tappable components like buttons etc. For example, we want the `onClick` to also fire if the user presses the button and then moves his finger out of the button before letting go.

In general, we need to add some state to all tappables and I thought a [Higher Order Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) would be ideal for this, so I made the following:

**HOC**

```
const withTouchable = WrappedComponent => {
    return class Touchable extends React.Component {
        onClick() {
            this.props.onClick();
        }

        onMouseLeave() {
            // Some complicated logic to determine if we want to fire onClick
            if(...) {
                this.props.onClick();
            }
        }

        // Other mouse and touch handlers
        // onMouseMove = ...

        render() {
            return (
                <WrappedComponent
                    {...this.props}

                    onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)}
                    onMouseLeave={this.onMouseLeave.bind(this)}

                    // other mouse and touch handlers
                />
            );
        }
    };
};
```

**Sample component we want to be clickable.**

```
const Heading = ({ title }) => <h1>{title}</h1>;
```

**Sample app**

```
const TouchableHeading = withTouchable(Heading);

class App extends React.Component {

    onClick() {
        console.log("title tapped")
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <TouchableHeading
                title="Some title"
                onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)}
            />
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Unfortunately this does not work, because although the `<WrappedComponent>` is returned with mouse and touch handlers, this is not used by the `<Heading>`. See [codepen.io/bvgZwb](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bvgZwb)

An alternative would be to wrap a div around the WrapperComponent:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div
            onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)}
            onMouseLeave={this.onMouseLeave.bind(this)}
            // other mouse and touch handlers
        >
            <WrappedComponent {...this.props}/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

See [codepen.io/xWgBMJ](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xWgBMJ). But this adds an extra DOM element, which is not ideal (it messes with the styling and there is no time to rewrite the whole app).

Is there another way I'm not thinking about to achieve this? I did look into [render props and using functions as children](https://codedaily.io/tutorials/6/Using-Functions-as-Children-and-Render-Props-in-React-Components) but I don't think it's possible to achieve my goal that way.

Note: Don't mind the `this.onClick.bind(this)`, [I know](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-no-bind.md).

Answer (score 1):

The only way to not use a wrapper and do what you want is to make use of rest props like

`const Heading = ({ title, ...rest }) => <h1 {...rest}>{title}</h1>;`

however if you are not careful with this, all your attributes will reach your DOM since React no longer does the attribute validation in the latest versions

or

make specifically add event attributes to Heading like

```
const Heading = ({ title, onClick, onMouseLeave }) => (
     <h1 
        onClick={onClick}
        onMouseLeave={onMouseLeave}
     >
       {title}
     </h1>
)
```